# Ax2009 Tree node export

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2009

Is there another way to export TreeNodes from AX2009 besides `TreeNode.treeNodeExport(filename)`?

Is there possibly a way of doing this based on the UtilElements table?

EDIT
When calling treeNodeExport while connected with the .Net Business connector, the method .treeNodeExport fails. I was wondering if there is another way of exporting a TreeNode to an xpo file in order to work around this. This occurs mainly with the ProjectNodes.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try and resolve the reason your method call fails.  Have you tried asserting write permissions first?

`new FileIoPermission(@'C:\MyOutput.xpo', 'w').assert();`

Does your `treeNodeExport` method call fail because of the file-system on either `client/server`? I.E. if you're making a call to export to `C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\MyXPO.xpo`, that location may not exist if it's on the server tier.

**Alternatively**, if you are using the business connector, which is using the `business connector user account`, then that user account may not have permission to write to the directory you are trying to export to.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your requirements are, but if you could use `treeNodeExport` and just want to convert a record of `UtilElements` into a `TreeNode` you could use the following snippet:

```
public static client void TestJob()
{
    UtilElements utilElements;
    ;

    // select firstOnly utilElements
    //     where utilElements ...  

    xUtilElements::getNode(utilElements).treeNodeExport(@'C:\temp\test.xpo');
}
```

Comment: Ok, I was thinking more of a different method than .treeNodeExport.